# Inherit vs Instantiate in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm still pretty confused what the best approach is when it's best to inherit from another class, or when you are better of returning a new instance of the other class. The aim is to get a chainable way to create various types of buttons. Here's some sample code:

```
class Button
  def initialize link
    @link = link
  end

  def color(color)
    @color = color
    return self
  end
end

# Now I'm wondering what is the best approach to do something like:

class RedButton < Button
  def initialize link
    super
    color('red')
  end
end

# or

class Redbutton
  def initialize link
    return Button.new(link).color('red')
  end
end
```

Or is this basically the same?

Comment: A class is a blueprint used to create instances. Instantiation creates, well, instances of the class. Inheritance creates a new class, i.e. a new blueprint. They are different concepts.

Comment: _"The aim is to get a chainable way to create various types of buttons"_ – inheritance is for specialization. If you want to extract color and shape from your `Button` class, use composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class is a blueprint used to create objects. Instantiation creates new instances of the class (new objects). Inheritance creates a new class, i.e. a new blueprint. They are different concepts.

The second example doesn't work as you think. The `initialize` method is the constructor of the class. It is invoked by the `new` class method when a new instance is created. It cannot return a value (well, it always returns a value but it is ignored).

The `Redbutton` class in the second example is a new empty class, not related in any way with the `Button` class. Its constructor creates a new instance of the `Button` class and returns it but the returned object is not stored anywhere and it is destroyed by the interpreter on the next garbage collection cycle.

The second `Redbutton` class is the same as:

```
class Redbutton
  def initialize link
  end
end
```

---

The first implementation of the `Redbutton` class (the one that extends `Button`) is the semantically correct one. It creates a `Button` object that has its `@color` property set to `'red'` during its creation.

---

**Update** (answer to the question posted in comments)

The best approach depends on a lot of factors. You'll discover it while you work on the project. If `RoundButton` and `SquareButton` provide **different functionality** than the base class (`Button`) then it makes sense to create separate classes for them. You'll encounter a challenge if you also need `RedRoundButton` (what class to extend? `RedButton` or `RoundButton`?) and you'll discover that many times inheritance is not the solution.

But if the only difference between `RedButton` and `Button` is **the value of one field (or several fields)** then you better create a factory method in class `Button` (or a factory class) that knows how to create and initialize a red button, a round button, a red round button etc. For example:

```
class Button
  def initialize link
    @link = link
  end

  def color(color)
    @color = color
    self
  end

  def shape(shape)
    @shape = shape
    self
  end

  def self.create(type, link)
    case type
    when 'RedButton'
        self.new(link).color('red')
    when 'RoundButton'
        self.new(link).shape('round')
    when 'RedRoundButton'
        self.new(link).color('red').shape('round')
    else
        raise 'Unknown type'
    end
  end
end

x = Button.create('RedButton', 4)
y = Button.create('RedRoundButton', 6)
```

Comment: Is I would continue to creatie a lot of similar buttons like this, maybe also RoundButton or SquareButton, is this still a viable approach?

Comment: The best approach depends on a lot of factors. You'll discover it while you work on the project. If `RoundButton` and `SquareButton` provide different functionality than the base class (`Button`) then it makes sense to create separate classes for them. You'll encounter a challenge if you also need `RedRoundButton` (what class to extend? `RedButton` or `RoundButton`?) and you'll discover that many times inheritance is not the solution.

Comment: @bo-oz Like I suggested in my answer, it *may* be better to inject the dependency here, e.g. `Button.new(link, color: 'green', shape: 'square')`. There's no silver bullet answer to every problem; you need to make a choice for which pattern to use for a given scenario!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the point of inheritance slightly.

The idea is to *extend or override the base class* with more custom behaviour. For example:

```
class Button
  def initialize(link)
    @link = link
  end

  def color
    nil # none by default!
  end
end

class RedButton < Button
  def color
    'red'
  end
end
```

Think of classes as "templates" for objects. In this case, `RedButton` is a "more specific template" than the generic `Button` template.

There are, of course, other design patterns that you could be using; inheritance is not the answer to every problem. For instance, may be better off to simply inject a dependency here (e.g. `Button.new(link, color: 'red')`!).